# how to update sling.properties

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

As per my requirement, I need to read some values from properties file when CQ starts. I'm thinking for a solution where I can update crx-quickstart\conf\sling.properties depending on my environment and then when CQ will start then it should read value from this properties file and then I can read from OSGI service. Any advice on how to read from sling.properties file?

Another solution that I'm thinking to create OSGI service which will read from some.properties  under c:/somefolder/myprop.properties and then I use @Reference.

Please let me know which approach is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to read properties when CQ starts? For what? Can you tell us something about the real requirements?

With this amount of information I would create an OSGi bundle with a service that takes such information not from a properties file but from OSGi configuration that can then be stored within the repository or at filesystem level under crx-quickstart/launchap/config.

HTH
Davide

Comment: can you please let me know how do I mention this logic in OSGI service?

Comment: ,I managed to get the logic to read configuaration. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sound like you need run modes and then use environment configuration nodes of the run mode for a service

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/configuring_cq.html#Run Modes